# Python Socket Server sends file request 3 times instead of once?

Tags: python, html, sockets, python-2.7

Making a simple python web server using sockets to start understanding how they work, but I think I'm lost on this on. 
 My python server is supposed to access a basic html file in the same directory and display it, once for every time it's requested. But this code for some reason sends the request 3 to 5 times...

```
from socket import *
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
port = 12030
server.bind((gethostname(), port))
server.listen(1)
while True:
    print 'Ready to serve'
    conection,  addr = server.accept()
    try:
        print 'Working'
        message = conection.recv(1024)
        filename = message.split()[1] #cuts off the '/' in the request page
        f = open(filename[1:])
        print message
        outputdata = f.read()
        print outputdata
        conection.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n')
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            conection.send(outputdata[i])
        conection.close()
    except IOError:
        print 'IO ERROR'
        print message
        print outputdata
        conection.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.close()
        conection.close()
        break;
```

This is the output from me opening the page in the browser.

```
-en 14:59:54  @ ・ー ・ 
python project.py 
Ready to serve
Working
<html><body><h1>Wurld</body></html>

Ready to serve
Working
IO ERROR
<html><body><h1>Wurld</body></html>

Ready to serve
Working
IO ERROR
<html><body><h1>Wurld</body></html>

Ready to serve
```

I've tried adding a `server.listen(1)` 
and a `conection.send("Content-Type:text/html\r\n")` , but neither of these do anything.
I'm not sure what the problem could be other than blocking how many times can be requested per minute?
Updated to print message every time

```
-en 15:33:26  @ ・ー ・ 
python project.py 
Ready to serve
Working
GET /HelloWorld.html HTTP/1.1
Host: seppala:12030
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8


<html><body><h1>Wurld</body></html>

Ready to serve
Working
IO ERROR
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: seppala:12030
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8


<html><body><h1>Wurld</body></html>

Ready to serve
Working
IO ERROR
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: seppala:12030
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8


<html><body><h1>Wurld</body></html>

Ready to serve
```

Comment: What's the value of message each time?

Comment: I added print message, updated my question with the result

Comment: I don't understand where `/favicon.ico` is coming from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your browser is requesting favicon.ico . Try adding a favicon.ico to your document root, or perhaps try a different browser. This problem isn't because of your script.